# What are examples of models for traffic sign detection that can be easily implemented?

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, deep-learning, tensorflow, reference-request

I'm working on a college project about traffic sign detection and I have to choose a paper to implement it, but I have basic knowledge of TensorFlow and I'm afraid of choosing a paper that I can't implement it.

What are examples of models for traffic sign detection that can be easily implemented?